# fix Selected startDate should be the next end Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, date, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation datepicker for two dates startDate and endDate.

1) On clicking of datepicker calendar, defaultly it is showing the today's date.

2) If I on change any date from startDate, for example If I select "10-10-2016".
without changing any date from endDate, if I open enddate calendar, it should start as "10-10-2016" only. But it is starting as an today's date.

3) My recuriment is, the selected startDate is the next end date in a calendar not in textfield. Please look at the images.

Please look at this fiddle,

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/du0a6tyu/)

Please see the first image.

[image]

I am selecting "14.07.2016" from startDate.

[image]

On Clicking of endDate, it has starting with today's Date. But it is disabled. It is correct. I want to start with "14.07.2016" only. Blue color active date should show on selected startDate.

[image]

See the last image. Upto "14.07.2016" all dates are disbled. But it is not starting with that date. Please help me how can I do this.

```js
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = jQuery('#startDate').fdatepicker({
  format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
  onRender: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
  }
}).data('datepicker');

var checkout = jQuery('#endDate').fdatepicker({
  format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
  onRender: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() < checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
  }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  checkout.hide();
}).data('datepicker');
```

```html
<input type="text" id="startDate" name="start_datum" class="input_text date" value="">

<input type="text" id="endDate" name="end_datum" class="input_text" value="">
```

Comment: They have given an example in **[`here too`](https://gist.github.com/najlepsiwebdesigner/f00af2b2dfbca6494d0a#file-gistfile1-html)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a change event to start date, to update the end date.

try this:-

```
var checkin = jQuery('#startDate').fdatepicker({
  format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
  onRender: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
  }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
    var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate());
    checkout.update(newDate);
    $('#endDate')[0].focus();
  }
}).data('datepicker');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/du0a6tyu/3/)

Comment: Sorry, I need without selecting end date, the field should be empty. But it is automatically taking the selecting startDate. I want to show only in calendar. Not in text field.

Comment: Here the problem is, First I am selecting any date from endDate, then If I select any new date from startDate, it will populate the same date  in endDate field also. It won't take the previously selected end Date. So this one is wrong.

Comment: it will only change the end date if the start date is greater than the end.

Comment: Please look at the images. My functionalities are woking. The only thing I just want to show the selected start date as in end date calendar. But when I click calendar field it is showing the current date.

Comment: looking through the documentation. this way is the only option i can see.